# Failed python socket (using OPC UA) connect to mock server from within Docker

Tags: python, docker, networking, opc, opc-ua

I am pretty sure that this is a standard network socket problem. I am currently dockerizing my application which makes use of the python py-opcua ( OPC UA ) package. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this, or any suggestions I could try out?

I have set up a mock server with nodes, which runs locally on my **Mac** machine (no Dockerization here!):

```
        self.server = Server()
        self.server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:50001/")

        # setup our own namespace, not really necessary but should as spec
        uri = "http://some-uri.com"
        self.idx = self.server.register_namespace(uri)

        # get Objects node, this is where we should put our custom stuff
        self.objects = self.server.get_objects_node()
        self.root = self.objects.add_object(self.idx, "Child")

        self._populate_server_with_variables()
        self.server.iserver.history_manager.set_storage(HistorySQLite("mock.db"))

        # Sample new values for all variables...
        self.start()

        self.make_all_variables_writable()
```

Now I am trying to connect to the above Server using the py-opcua `Client` class, which connects as follows (this part runs from within a docker container! again, from my local machine):

```
        self.client = Client(
            "opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:50001/",
            timeout=60.
        )

        self.client.connect()  # Where my application fails from within Docker!

        self.root = self.client.get_root_node()
```

When I run the docker container, the client is not able to connect to the mock server. Specifically, when a connection is (tried to be) established, the docker container crashes.

I tried running the following `docker run` commands, which all produce the same error:

```
docker run --env-file env/.local-docker.env -i --rm -p 50001:50001 image_name
```

```
docker run --env-file env/.local-docker.env -i --rm --network host image_name
```

```
docker run --env-file env/.local-docker.env -i --rm --network=host image_name
```

The error which I get, is always a failed socket connection from the client side. Specifically, I get the following error message:

```
Logfile will be save in:  ./logs/log_2020-03-01 18:54:36.769166.log
Connecting to... "opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:50001/"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/app/deploy/middleware/loop.py", line 96, in <module>
    opc_reader_rt = RealTimeReader(opc_path)
  File "/app/deploy/opc_client/dataset.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.client.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opcua/client/client.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connect_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opcua/client/client.py", line 281, in connect_socket
    self.uaclient.connect_socket(self.server_url.hostname, self.server_url.port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 256, in connect_socket
    return self._uasocket.connect_socket(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 155, in connect_socket
    sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Docker on a Mac uses a VM so you can't use traditional host networking - you need to use a network both environments are aware of and can connect to. The easiest way for temporary testing is to use the local IP of the Mac to connect _from_ the container, eg., `10.x.x.x` (use `ifconfig` to find actual value). Another option would be to create a bridge network via 
[docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) that both would share if you have a dynamic local IP.

Comment: @ldg So I tried setting up a common network, docker compose, and connection to the specified mac-IP (10.x.x.x) which I found using ifconfig. None of these approaches seems to be working, they all produce the same error. Could it be perhaps due to some docker-desktop settings that are installed wrongly?

Comment: I also create a python shell to check if DNS resolution works. It does. It also works locally, without docker. Checking right now if I can use a non-urllib library to connect to the mock server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the environment variable was wrongly reading a double-quote a la https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3702